# Disqus having issues to load on a cached version of my pages

Tags: disqus

I have a disqus enabled blog and the disqus javascript loads the comment form well. Recently, i introduced caching to my blog posts so i can speed up pageload time and reduce bandwidth.

This is how i cache my blog posts: once a new post is created, i view it and the disqus comment works fine however, on the first view of my page, my script creates a static html file of the page and stores it on the server. on subsequent request, the html file is loaded not a database request.

I have discovered that on the cached html page, the comment form does not load.

Please how can i go about this, has anyone experienced this kind of error before?

Also if its worth mentioning am not using wordpress

Comment: It might be helpful to know a) which caching service you are using, and b) what the HTML markup looks like on the cached page.

Answer (score 0):

After series of googling and hours of debugging, I have found out my error.

Since the post titles were created dynamically, It contains some characters that needed to be escaped.such as `disqus_title = ''` contained titles that had ' in them, this caused the JS to break.